# How do I point to an existing entry in a many-to-many relation?

Tags: database, django

I'm having trouble with double entries in my django database and hope for your help. Let's say I have two tables (`person, car`) which are joined via a many-to-many field. Each new entry inserts one person and, say, their three favourite cars. Each person is unique, the cars are not. Now, before adding a car I want to check if said car is already in the `car` table (i.e. someone else also likes it). If so, don't add a new car entry, but link to the existing entry. This is what I have so far:

```
newPerson = project.models.Person.objects.create(…)

for i in range(len(cars)):
    newCar = project.models.Car.objects.create(car=cars[i])
    newPerson.cars.add(newCar)
```

How do I make sure no car is entered twice and `person` still points to the correct cars?

Comment: +1 for wonderfully clear question. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to insert only if the object doesnt exist.